# Quantifying importance of a parameter in neural networks' prediction

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, nonparametric

Say I'm given a neural network, parameterized by a $d$-dimensional vector $\theta$, and an input $x$.

Given the prediction of this model $f_{\theta}(x)$, can I somehow quantify importance of each of $d$ parameters ?

For example, if a parameter is attributed a low importance, setting this parameter to 0 shouldn't change the model's output too much where as doing the same thing for an important parameter should change the model's prediction rather significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to this question in the following paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00796

Basically, the Empirical Fisher Information Matrix (FIM) seems to be the answer. In particular, it's a $d$x$d$ matrix where $d$ is the number of parameters of the model. The diagonal of this matrix gives a value for each parameter that roughly quantifies its importance.

I've also found [this blog post](https://andrewliao11.github.io/blog/fisher-info-matrix/) very useful to understand and figure out how to compute FIM in a practical setting.